# Retrofit 2 TLS 1.1 on Android 4.1

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I tried to set the supported TLS versions with this code:

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_3, TlsVersion.TLS_1_2, TlsVersion.TLS_1_1)
            .cipherSuites(
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
            .build();

    builder.connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));
```

I use these libs:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

But I got this exception:

> HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownServiceException: Unable to find acceptable protocols. isFallback=false, modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_3, TLS_1_2, TLS_1_1], supportsTlsExtensions=true)], supported protocols=[SSLv3, TLSv1]

Can you help me, how can use TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 on android 4.1?

Comment: Are you using [the `ProviderInstaller`'s `installIfNeeded`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html)? If not, that might be necessary to do before you create your http client.

Comment: No, but I will try it.

Comment: @Michael, thanks its working!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to dig into SSLSocketfactory and find a [TLSSocketFactory](https://gist.github.com/fkrauthan/ac8624466a4dee4fd02f) by fkrauthan. Putting into my project as it is.

Getting things together from different sources and created "MyTrustManager".

```
public class MyTrustManager {
public X509TrustManager trustManagerForCertificates(InputStream in) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    Collection<? extends Certificate> certificates = certificateFactory.generateCertificates(in);
    if (certificates.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected non-empty set of trusted certificates");
    }

    char[] password = "password".toCharArray(); // Any password will work.
    KeyStore keyStore = newEmptyKeyStore(password);
    int index = 0;
    for (Certificate certificate : certificates) {
        String certificateAlias = Integer.toString(index++);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry(certificateAlias, certificate);
    }

    // Use it to build an X509 trust manager.
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
            KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password);
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
            TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
    if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:"
                + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
    }
    return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
}

private KeyStore newEmptyKeyStore(char[] password) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    try {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        InputStream in = null; // By convention, 'null' creates an empty key store.
        keyStore.load(in, password);
        return keyStore;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

public InputStream trustedCertificatesInputStream() {
    String comodoRsaCertificationAuthority = ""
            + "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            + "MIIF2DCCA8CgAwIBAgIQTKr5yttjb+Af907YWwOGnTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADCB\n"
            + "hTELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G\n"
            + "A1UEBxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UEChMRQ09NT0RPIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxKzApBgNV\n"
            + "BAMTIkNPTU9ETyBSU0EgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkwHhcNMTAwMTE5\n"
            + "MDAwMDAwWhcNMzgwMTE4MjM1OTU5WjCBhTELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgT\n"
            + "EkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4GA1UEBxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UEChMR\n"
            + "Q09NT0RPIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxKzApBgNVBAMTIkNPTU9ETyBSU0EgQ2VydGlmaWNh\n"
            + "dGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkwggIiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4ICDwAwggIKAoICAQCR\n"
            + "6FSS0gpWsawNJN3Fz0RndJkrN6N9I3AAcbxT38T6KhKPS38QVr2fcHK3YX/JSw8X\n"
            + "pz3jsARh7v8Rl8f0hj4K+j5c+ZPmNHrZFGvnnLOFoIJ6dq9xkNfs/Q36nGz637CC\n"
            + "9BR++b7Epi9Pf5l/tfxnQ3K9DADWietrLNPtj5gcFKt+5eNu/Nio5JIk2kNrYrhV\n"
            + "/erBvGy2i/MOjZrkm2xpmfh4SDBF1a3hDTxFYPwyllEnvGfDyi62a+pGx8cgoLEf\n"
            + "Zd5ICLqkTqnyg0Y3hOvozIFIQ2dOciqbXL1MGyiKXCJ7tKuY2e7gUYPDCUZObT6Z\n"
            + "+pUX2nwzV0E8jVHtC7ZcryxjGt9XyD+86V3Em69FmeKjWiS0uqlWPc9vqv9JWL7w\n"
            + "qP/0uK3pN/u6uPQLOvnoQ0IeidiEyxPx2bvhiWC4jChWrBQdnArncevPDt09qZah\n"
            + "SL0896+1DSJMwBGB7FY79tOi4lu3sgQiUpWAk2nojkxl8ZEDLXB0AuqLZxUpaVIC\n"
            + "u9ffUGpVRr+goyhhf3DQw6KqLCGqR84onAZFdr+CGCe01a60y1Dma/RMhnEw6abf\n"
            + "Fobg2P9A3fvQQoh/ozM6LlweQRGBY84YcWsr7KaKtzFcOmpH4MN5WdYgGq/yapiq\n"
            + "crxXStJLnbsQ/LBMQeXtHT1eKJ2czL+zUdqnR+WEUwIDAQABo0IwQDAdBgNVHQ4E\n"
            + "FgQUu69+Aj36pvE8hI6t7jiY7NkyMtQwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMA8GA1UdEwEB\n"
            + "/wQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEMBQADggIBAArx1UaEt65Ru2yyTUEUAJNMnMvl\n"
            + "wFTPoCWOAvn9sKIN9SCYPBMtrFaisNZ+EZLpLrqeLppysb0ZRGxhNaKatBYSaVqM\n"
            + "4dc+pBroLwP0rmEdEBsqpIt6xf4FpuHA1sj+nq6PK7o9mfjYcwlYRm6mnPTXJ9OV\n"
            + "2jeDchzTc+CiR5kDOF3VSXkAKRzH7JsgHAckaVd4sjn8OoSgtZx8jb8uk2Intzna\n"
            + "FxiuvTwJaP+EmzzV1gsD41eeFPfR60/IvYcjt7ZJQ3mFXLrrkguhxuhoqEwWsRqZ\n"
            + "CuhTLJK7oQkYdQxlqHvLI7cawiiFwxv/0Cti76R7CZGYZ4wUAc1oBmpjIXUDgIiK\n"
            + "boHGhfKppC3n9KUkEEeDys30jXlYsQab5xoq2Z0B15R97QNKyvDb6KkBPvVWmcke\n"
            + "jkk9u+UJueBPSZI9FoJAzMxZxuY67RIuaTxslbH9qh17f4a+Hg4yRvv7E491f0yL\n"
            + "S0Zj/gA0QHDBw7mh3aZw4gSzQbzpgJHqZJx64SIDqZxubw5lT2yHh17zbqD5daWb\n"
            + "QOhTsiedSrnAdyGN/4fy3ryM7xfft0kL0fJuMAsaDk527RH89elWsn2/x20Kk4yl\n"
            + "0MC2Hb46TpSi125sC8KKfPog88Tk5c0NqMuRkrF8hey1FGlmDoLnzc7ILaZRfyHB\n"
            + "NVOFBkpdn627G190\n"
            + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
    String entrustRootCertificateAuthority = ""
            + "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            + "MIIEkTCCA3mgAwIBAgIERWtQVDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBsDELMAkGA1UEBhMC\n"
            + "VVMxFjAUBgNVBAoTDUVudHJ1c3QsIEluYy4xOTA3BgNVBAsTMHd3dy5lbnRydXN0\n"
            + "Lm5ldC9DUFMgaXMgaW5jb3Jwb3JhdGVkIGJ5IHJlZmVyZW5jZTEfMB0GA1UECxMW\n"
            + "KGMpIDIwMDYgRW50cnVzdCwgSW5jLjEtMCsGA1UEAxMkRW50cnVzdCBSb290IENl\n"
            + "cnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5MB4XDTA2MTEyNzIwMjM0MloXDTI2MTEyNzIw\n"
            + "NTM0MlowgbAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1FbnRydXN0LCBJbmMuMTkw\n"
            + "NwYDVQQLEzB3d3cuZW50cnVzdC5uZXQvQ1BTIGlzIGluY29ycG9yYXRlZCBieSBy\n"
            + "ZWZlcmVuY2UxHzAdBgNVBAsTFihjKSAyMDA2IEVudHJ1c3QsIEluYy4xLTArBgNV\n"
            + "BAMTJEVudHJ1c3QgUm9vdCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIEF1dGhvcml0eTCCASIwDQYJ\n"
            + "KoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALaVtkNC+sZtKm9I35RMOVcF7sN5EUFo\n"
            + "Nu3s/poBj6E4KPz3EEZmLk0eGrEaTsbRwJWIsMn/MYszA9u3g3s+IIRe7bJWKKf4\n"
            + "4LlAcTfFy0cOlypowCKVYhXbR9n10Cv/gkvJrT7eTNuQgFA/CYqEAOwwCj0Yzfv9\n"
            + "KlmaI5UXLEWeH25DeW0MXJj+SKfFI0dcXv1u5x609mhF0YaDW6KKjbHjKYD+JXGI\n"
            + "rb68j6xSlkuqUY3kEzEZ6E5Nn9uss2rVvDlUccp6en+Q3X0dgNmBu1kmwhH+5pPi\n"
            + "94DkZfs0Nw4pgHBNrziGLp5/V6+eF67rHMsoIV+2HNjnogQi+dPa2MsCAwEAAaOB\n"
            + "sDCBrTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zArBgNVHRAEJDAi\n"
            + "gA8yMDA2MTEyNzIwMjM0MlqBDzIwMjYxMTI3MjA1MzQyWjAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBRo\n"
            + "kORnpKZTgMeGZqTx90tD+4S9bTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUaJDkZ6SmU4DHhmak8fdLQ/uE\n"
            + "vW0wHQYJKoZIhvZ9B0EABBAwDhsIVjcuMTo0LjADAgSQMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUA\n"
            + "A4IBAQCT1DCw1wMgKtD5Y+iRDAUgqV8ZyntyTtSx29CW+1RaGSwMCPeyvIWonX9t\n"
            + "O1KzKtvn1ISMY/YPyyYBkVBs9F8U4pN0wBOeMDpQ47RgxRzwIkSNcUesyBrJ6Zua\n"
            + "AGAT/3B+XxFNSRuzFVJ7yVTav52Vr2ua2J7p8eRDjeIRRDq/r72DQnNSi6q7pynP\n"
            + "9WQcCk3RvKqsnyrQ/39/2n3qse0wJcGE2jTSW3iDVuycNsMm4hH2Z0kdkquM++v/\n"
            + "eu6FSqdQgPCnXEqULl8FmTxSQeDNtGPPAUO6nIPcj2A781q0tHuu2guQOHXvgR1m\n"
            + "0vdXcDazv/wor3ElhVsT/h5/WrQ8\n"
            + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
    return new Buffer()
            .writeUtf8(comodoRsaCertificationAuthority)
            .writeUtf8(entrustRootCertificateAuthority)
            .inputStream();
}
```

}

Setting MyTrustManger

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
setSSLSocketFactory(httpClient);
```

Here the setSSLSocketFactory

```
private static void setSSLSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient) {
    try {
        MyTrustManager myTrustManager = new MyTrustManager();
        TrustManager trustManager = myTrustManager.trustManagerForCertificates(
                myTrustManager.trustedCertificatesInputStream());
        httpClient.sslSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager) trustManager);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```